# Is there a network digram tool that can export to html with links to the services / hosts ?

Tags: networking

Anyone know of a (free online or free linux-based) tool that can export a Diagram (Network Diagram) to HTML and link Hosts / Devices to its IP / Services ? E.g. If I had a router item, and I specify its IP with access via SSH, if I click on that host, i'd like it to start the default ssh client to that IP address...

Would be great if anyone can let me know?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything for Linux that will generate a diagram (aside from much larger software packages like [Zenoss](http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-5858), [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/features.php), and [Nagios](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/Nagios/check_find_new_hosts/details)).

Out of the box, [Nmap](http://nmap.org) can generate a decent report of all ports/services running on a network.

1. Scan network and format result as XML:

   ```
   $ sudo nmap -sV 10.1.1.1-254 -oX scan.xml
   ```
2. Convert to HTML page (using XSL stylesheet distributed with nmap):

   ```
   $ xsltproc scan.xml > scan.html
   ```

Creating a custom XSL stylesheet (nmap --stylesheet  option), you should be able to create a list of hosts and clickable service links.

Answer (score 0):

One option, with some effort, is to use nagios for this.

Check [this nice diagrams](http://www.nagios.com/products/nagioscore/screenshots) to see if is good for your purpose.